# Rip Info From MYSQL To JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, database

Doesn't got any errors in NetBeans until I run it, then the console get invaded with errors... I've been struggling with this database rip (my first) for a while and I cant seem to figure it out...
Hugs for help!

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         


    connection();
        String userName = "abc";
        String password = "abc";
        String url = "abc";

    try{
        try (Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password)) {
            PreparedStatement statement;
            statement = connect.prepareStatement("select * from hemligt (tjanst,vem,service,bestalls,day)");

            statement.executeUpdate();
            statement.close();
            connect.close();

        }
        String report = getString("tjanst" + "vem" + "service" + "bestalls" + "day");

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "sent");
        System.out.println(report);
    }catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace () ;

    }
}
```

I made a working "write to database" code and just changed it a bit, that's probably the reason..

Error;

```
run:
java.sql.SQLException: Can not issue executeUpdate() for SELECTs
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1086)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:975)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:920)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2407)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2366)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2350)
at AppPackage.NewJFrame.jButton1ActionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:92)
at AppPackage.NewJFrame.access$000(NewJFrame.java:22)
at AppPackage.NewJFrame$1.actionPerformed(NewJFrame.java:46)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at     javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3320)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:735)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(EventQueue.java:103)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:694)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:692)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at     java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:708)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:706)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:705)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:242)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:150)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:146)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:138)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:91)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: too many seconds)
```

Comment: You will need to post the error in full if you want effective help.

Comment: An `executeUpdate` [is for statements to modify the database (INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html), not for `SELECT`s.

Comment: Your error is about as clear as it's going to get. Please read a [tutorial on JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) - you need to learn to walk before you can run.

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute a query (that reads from the db) not an update (the edits data in the DB)

Refer: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

Instead of:

```
statement.executeUpdate();
```

You need:

```
String query = "select * from hemligt (tjanst,vem,service,bestalls,day)";
ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query)
```

Refer to the link for an example of how you can extract the necessary info from the ResultSet obtained by executing the query.